# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline' while trying to search for a string and print the line

Tags: python, input, readline

I am trying to take an input from user and search for the string from a file and then print the line. When I try to execute I keep getting this error. My code is

```
file = open("file.txt", 'r')
data = file.read()
zinput = str(input("Enter the word you want me to search: "))
for zinput in data:
    line = data.readline()
    print (line)
```

Comment: Your code is wrong in so many level. You did `read()` from file and then using `readline()` in loop which basically overwrites the user input.

Comment: And then you overwrite the `zinput` from the input call with every line in the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many things to improve in your code.

- `data` is a string, and `str` has no attribute `readline()`.
- `read` will read the whole content from file. Don't do this.
- `break` the loop once you find `zinput`.
- don't forget to close the file, when you are done.

The algorithm is really simple:

1) file object is an iterable, read it line by line.

2) If a line contains your `zinput`, print it.

Code:

```
file = open("file.txt", 'r')
zinput = str(input("Enter the word you want me to search: "))
for line in file:
    if zinput in line:
        print line
        break
file.close()
```

Optionally, you can use `with` to make things easier and shorter. It will close the file for you.

Code:

```
zinput = str(input("Enter the word you want me to search: "))
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:    
        if zinput in line:
            print line
            break
```

Comment: you can also show him the file handling using `with`

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues looks to be with calling `readline()` on the data that is returned from your opened file.  Another way to approach this would be:

```
flag = True
zInput = ""
while flag:
    zInput = str(raw_input("Enter the word you want me to search: "))
    if len(zInput) > 0:
        flag = False
    else: 
        print("Not a valid input, please try again")

with open("file.txt", 'r') as fileObj:
    fileString = fileObj.read()
    if len(fileString) > 0 and fileString == zInput:
        print("You have found a matching phrase")
```

One thing that I forgot to mention is that I tested this code with Python 2.7 and it looks like you are using Python 3.* because of the use of input() and not raw_input() for STDIN.

In your example, please use:

```
zInput = str(input("Enter the word you want me to search: "))
```

For Python 3.*